# R keep randomly generating numbers until all numbers within specified range are present

Tags: r, loops, random, conditional-statements, repeat

My aim is to randomly generate a vector of integers using R, which is populated by numbers between `1-8`. However, I want to keep growing the vector until all the numbers between 1:8 are represented at least once, e.g. `1,4,6,2,2,3,5,1,4,7,6,8`.

I am able to generate single numbers or a sequence of numbers using `sample`

```
x=sample(1:8,1, replace=T)
>x
[1] 6
```

I have played around with the `repeat` function to see how it might work with `sample` and I can at least get the generation to stop when one specific number occurs, e.g.

```
repeat {
   print(x)
   x = sample(1:8, 1, replace=T)
   if (x == 3){
       break
   }
}
```

Which gives:

```
[1] 3
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 2
```

I am struggling now to work out how to stop number generation once all numbers between `1:8` are present. Additionally, I know that the above code is only printing the sequence as it is generated and not storing it as a vector. Any advice pointing me in the right direction would be really appreciated!

Comment: You could look at the `intersect` and `setDiff` functions, but that might be too expensive for your use case.

Comment: chris_90, if one of the answers meets your needs, please "accept" it (one only) by selecting the checkmark to the left of it. Optionally up-vote one or both of the answers you find at least partially useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine for `1:8` but might not always be a good idea.

```
foo = integer(0)    
set.seed(42)
while(TRUE){
    foo = c(foo, sample(1:8, 1))
    if(all(1:8 %in% foo)) break
}
foo
# [1] 8 8 3 7 6 5 6 2 6 6 4 6 8 3 4 8 8 1
```

If you have more than `1:8`, it may be better to [obtain the average number of tries (N) required to get all the numbers at least once](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1078030/404422) and then sample N numbers such that all numbers are sampled at least once.

```
set.seed(42)
vec = 1:8
N = ceiling(sum(length(vec)/(1:length(vec))))
foo = sample(c(vec, sample(vec, N - length(vec), TRUE)))
foo
# [1] 3 6 8 3 8 8 6 4 5 6 1 6 4 6 6 3 5 7 2 2 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Taking cue off of d.b, here's a slightly more verbose method that is more memory-efficient (and a little faster too, though I doubt speed is your issue):

Differences:

- pre-allocate memory in chunks (size 100 here), mitigates the problem with extend-by-one vector work; allocating and extending 100 (or even 1000) at a time is much lower cost
- compare only the newest number instead of all numbers each time (the first `n-1` numbers have already been tabulated, no need to do that again)

Code:

```
microbenchmark(
  r2evans = {
    emptyvec100 <- integer(100)
    counter <- 0
    out <- integer(0)
    unseen <- seq_len(n)
    set.seed(42)
    repeat {
      if (counter %% 100 == 0) out <- c(out, emptyvec100)
      counter <- counter+1
      num <- sample(n, size=1)
      unseen <- unseen[unseen != num]
      out[counter] <- num
      if (!length(unseen)) break
    }
    out <- out[1:counter]
  },
  d.b = {
    foo = integer(0)    
    set.seed(42)
    while(TRUE){
      foo = c(foo, sample(1:n, 1))
      if(all(1:n %in% foo)) break
    }
  }, times = 100, unit = 'us')
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  r2evans 1090.007 1184.639 1411.531 1228.947 1320.845 11344.24  1000
#      d.b 1242.440 1372.264 1835.974 1441.916 1597.267 14592.74  1000
```

(This is intended neither as code-golf nor speed-optimization. My primary goal is to argue *against* extend-by-one vector work, and suggest a more efficient comparison technique.)

As d.b further suggested, this works fine for `1:8` but may run into trouble with larger numbers. If we extend `n` up:

[image: updated benchmark]

(**Edit:** with d.b's code changes, the execution times are much closer, and not nearly as exponential looking. Apparently the removal of `unique` had significant benefits to his code.)

Comment: Nice ... now my time/efficiency arguments don't carry as much weight :-)